# Removing Toolbar on longclick the item

Tags: android, contextmenu, contextual-action-bar, recyclerview-layout, onitemlongclicklistener

How to replace toolbar with contextual menu .... I had tried but i got 2 toolbar one is required contextual menu and other is normal toolbar as shown in pic

[image: I want to remove toolbar named international in it]

Comment: post your `onlongclicklistner` code

Comment: ActionMode   mActionMode=startSupportActionMode(this);

Comment: Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chatselectedmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }   Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }
 Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                deleteRows();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }